# Need an element to behave like position:fixed, but only within its parent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

If it makes a difference in this case, I'm using Twitter Bootstrap. I've attempted to use affix, but that allows the element to break out of the parent.

Let's say I have a list of items on the page. Each item is laid out as follows:

```
<h3>Item name</h3>
<div class = "row">
   <div class = "col-md-10">
      <figure>
         <img src = "/assets/img/image.jpg" class = "img-responsive" />
      </figure>
   </div>
   <div class = "col-md-2" style = "text-align: center">
      <div class = "content">
         <p>Tip about this picture</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want the div containing the p element to move down when the user scrolls, similar to a fixed position div, but stop when it reaches the end of the parent container, so I don't continue seeing that div when the image it describes is no longer on screen. I've attempted fixed positioning, fixed positioning inside absolute positioning, and the affix feature of Twitter Bootstrap. They all allow the item to break containment. Is there a way to do this without javascript?

Comment: can u share your css also...

Comment: It's standard Twitter Bootstrap. I haven't made any changes to the base css or used any custom classes.

Comment: Is this the kind of behaviour you want? http://www.wduffy.co.uk/jScroll/

Comment: Yeah, that looks about right, with the exception of the delay. Can the delay be disabled, or possibly the animation altogether?

Comment: @DarrenS Bad example, as jScroll seems to be bugged in the current Chrome.

Comment: @modiX Not suprised it's several years old. I was trying to confirm the desired behavior more than suggest anyone to use a +3yr old plugin without testing it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly easy to do with HTML and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCuRq/.

HTML:

```
see fiddle
```

CSS:

```
*, :before, :after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

body p + p,
.container + p {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.container > .content {
    width: 80%;
    outline: 2px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
}

.container:before {
    content: "This shows dynamic usage of fixed positioning";
    display: none;
}

.container:hover:before {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    width: 15%;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    outline: 2px solid #bbb;
    padding: 10px;
    font: normal 10px/2 Sans-Serif;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the parent `div` to `position:relative` and the elements inside the parent div to `position:absolute`. This you can adjust the location of your elements within the parent `div` using `top`, `bottom`, `right` and `left`.

Example:

```
div.parent {
  position: relative;
}

div.parent div.element {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3teAj/

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:-
`p {
     overflow : auto;
 }

div.content {
       position : relative;
 }`

Comment: Instead of posting "solutions" like these, crank jsfiddle up and try it on your own and see if it works.  If it does, then post.